# Reuse month columns in SwiftUI Chart

Tags: swiftui, charts

I have a chart which displays data over time (months in my case). The data for this chart is randomly generated by getting any date from now to 500 days in the past (chartDate), and a random number (sales). It generates 500 of these rows.

```
func dailySales2() -> [(chartDate: Date, year: String, sales: Int)] {
    var temp: [(chartDate: Date, year: String, sales: Int)] = []
    
    for _ in 1...500 {
        let dateT = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -Int.random(in: 1...500), to: Date())!
        temp.append((chartDate: dateT, year: dateT.formatted(.dateTime.year()), sales: Int.random(in: 100...500)))
    }
    
    return temp.sorted(by: { $0.chartDate < $1.chartDate })
}

Chart {
            ForEach(dailySales2(), id: \.chartDate) { chartD in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Day", chartD.chartDate, unit: .month),
                    y: .value("Sales", chartD.sales)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Year:", chartD.year))
            }
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) {
                AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.narrow), centered: true)
            }
        }
```

This generates A S O N D J F M A M J J A S O N D columns (August 2021 - December 2021 and then January 2022 - December 2022). How do I go about only having one set of January - December columns and putting both years into these columns (separated by series)? Thanks.

Having 12 columns, one for each month, which any year uses.